# AJAX and PHP sending "HTTP get request" to the same page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My application gathers some client related information via JavaScript and submits it via AJAX to a php page.

See the code below:

**index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function postClientData(){
            var client_data = new Array(screen.availHeight, screen.availWidth);
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    if(this.responseText == client_data[0]){
                        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Client data successfully submitted!";
                    }

                }
            };

            var parameters = "ajax.php?screen_height=" + client_data[0] + "&screen_width=" + client_data[1];
            xmlhttp.open("GET", parameters, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="postClientData()">
    <span id="message"></span></p>
</body>

</html>
```

**ajax.php**

```
<?php
echo $_REQUEST["screen_height"];
//Does something else...
?>
```

I was wondering if I could merge the ajax.php content to my index.php and eliminate ajax.php. When I try adding the code, I probably get into a endless loop since I don't get my "success" message.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: AFAIK, no. You will need a server side script and an address to that file to make an AJAX request. Why do you want to merge the files, by the way?

Comment: Yes, you could, but I would not recommend it, as it's (more or less) a violation of the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, IMO I would definitely keep this specific logic separated in the `ajax.php` file.

If you do really want to merge, add it to the top of index.php (before printing data):

```
if (isset($_GET['screen_height'])) && isset($_GET['screen_width']) {
    // Execute specific logic and exit to prevent sending the HTML.
    exit;
}
```